# Show that $\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2 + 8}$ does not converge to 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So we need to show that:$ \exists \epsilon > 0, \forall X \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n > X,|\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2 + 8}| \ge \epsilon $.

$|\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2 + 8}| = \frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2 + 8} > \frac{2n^2-n^2}{8n^2 + 2n^2}$ for n $\ge$ 2.

So $ \epsilon > \frac{1}{10} ? $

Comment: How do you justify the first inequality in your second line?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: $\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2+8}=\frac14\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}=\frac14(1 -\frac2{n^2+1})$ Can you see it now?

Comment: @Michael: To answer Clayton's question, you must simply assert that $n$ is greater than some value.  Incidentally, are you sure that the quantifiers shouldn't be $\exists \varepsilon  > 0, \exists X \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n > X$?

Comment: I suppose if all you want to show is that it doesn't converge to $0$, the quantifiers as stated are OK.

Comment: @BrianTung: My question isn't answered as you stated. He makes both the numerator smaller *and* the denominator larger, so his inequality as stated isn't correct.

Comment: Ooh, you're quite right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Clayton: But on second thought, I think that's exactly why his inequality is fine.  We observe that $n^2 > 2$ and $2n^2 \geq 8$, so $\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2+8} > \frac{2n^2-n^2}{8n^2+8} \geq \frac{2n^2-n^2}{8n^2+2n^2} = \frac{n^2}{10n^2} = \frac{1}{10}$.  I don't think there's anything wrong there for $n \geq 2$, is there?

Comment: @BrianTung: Check the edit; he reversed the direction of his inequality (which makes it correct now).

Comment: You are right, but I had already noticed that; I assumed it was a typo, since the first line of his question indicates (correctly, for showing the limit is not $0$) that the aim is to show that the function exceeds $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all you are interested in showing is that the limit isn't $0$, we follow the approach you took: $$\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2+2}\geq\frac{2n^2-n^2}{8n^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{9}.$$ The inequality follows since $2n^2-2\geq n^2$ for $n>1$ and $8n^2+2<9n^2$ for $n>2$. In particular, we see that $$\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2+2}>\frac{1}{9}$$ for all $n>2$. Thus, if we take any $\varepsilon<\frac19$, we have that $|x_n|\geq\varepsilon>0$ for all $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\varepsilon = \frac{1}{10}$ does work, and so does any value less than $\frac{1}{4}$, which is the actual limit as $n \to \infty$.  (It approaches $\frac{1}{4}$ from beneath, so $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$ itself does not work.)

Comment: As the proposition is quantified currently, I think this works.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Oh not at all.  It's worth pointing out, surely.  There are framings of this problem where that might come into play; I'm just asserting that this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

$${2n^2 - 2\over 8n^2 + 8}= {1 - 1/n^2\over 4 + 4/n^2}\to {1\over 4} $$
as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2+8}=\frac{2-\frac{2}{n^2}}{8+\frac{8}{n^2}} $  so taking limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we get $1/4$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2n^2-2}{8n^2 + 8}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{8n^2-8}{8n^2+8}=\frac{1}{4}(1-\frac{16}{8n^2+8})=\frac{1}{4}(1-\frac{2}{n^2+1})$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$
\dfrac{2n^2-2}{8n^2 + 8}
\ge \dfrac{3}{20}
$
for all $n \ge 2$
because the inequality simplifies to $n^2 \ge 4$.